# Embedded Message Driven Resource Adapter fails to deploy

Tags: jboss, wildfly, ear, wildfly-8, jca

I have been struggling to get an example of a Message driven (inbound) resource adapter to deploy and interact with an EAR on Wildfly 8.2.0.

I used this [Java EE 7 JCA](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jca) sample as the basis of my application.

I can see in the log files that the Resource Adapter gets deployed

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.RADeployer] (MSC service thread 1-2)
 IJ020002: Deployed: file:/C:/Software/jboss/wildfly/8.2.0.Final/standalone/tmp/
vfs/deployment/deployment4490b91cd6391845/jca-ra.rar-86794a0699d3da23/contents/
```

but when the MDB gets initialised I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014521: No message listener
of type org.javaee7.jca.filewatch.adapter.FileSystemWatcher found in
resource adapter jcaInflowApp.ear#jca-ra.rar
```

The message listener is definitely in the RAR and the RAR is embedded in that location in the EAR.

I've uploaded the code base that I've been working on up to [github](https://github.com/timothysparg/JCA-Inflow-Wildfly) - hopefully somebody can peruse and see what the issue is?

**EDIT** for anybody that wants to see a working JBoss example please see the [github repo](https://github.com/timothysparg/JCA-Inflow-Wildfly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is duplicate JAR's containing message listener within your EAR. Change the scope of JAR to `provided` so that it does not get bundled inside `lib` folder. I've sent you a [PR](https://github.com/timothysparg/JCA-Inflow-Wildfly/pull/1) with the fix.